# Post request error: Missing or Invalid Post Body

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, http-post

I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure why:

```
{"success":false,"errors":["Missing or invalid POST body."],"results":[]}
```

I'm not sure if there is a problem with how I have my code structured, sending bad json, or what. If you could give me an idea of where to troubleshoot this, that would be great. Thanks. Here is how I have my settings:

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "bearer " + bearer_token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}


data = {
        'limit':10,
        'sort':"MinPrice DESC",
        'filters':[
            {
                'name':'SetName',
                'values':'All'
            }
        ]
    }

url = 'http://api.tcgplayer.com/V1.9.0/catalog/categories/3/search'

def catalog_data():
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(r.text)

catalog_data()
```

Comment: Try with `requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)`, it might help. At first glance, there's nothing wrong with the code. Might need the API doc however. And change `bearer` by `Bearer`, the API might not handle your authorization correctly.

Comment: @JeanRostan Making the change `json=data` worked. Than you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the change from `data=data` to `json=data` allowed my Post data to be read properly.